# Webrtc.Peerconnection using PeerJs

Tags: javascript, webrtc

It's my first time to work with PeerJs for WEBRTC.I have a problem for call another person.

Here is my code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        var peer = new Peer($.jStorage.get('numero'), {host:'localhost', port:9000,debug: 3});


        peer.on('open', function(id) {
          console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);

        });


        function bell(numero)  
        {
            navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {


                     var localStream = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);               


                     $('#my_self').attr('src',localStream);

                     var call = peer.call(numero,stream);

                        call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {


                            $('#caller').attr('src',remoteStream);
                        });

                        call.on('error', function(err) {

                          //error   
                        });

                },
                function(err) {

                            //errr

                    }

                }
            );
        }


        peer.on('call', function(call) {

                navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {


                     var localStream;= window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);


                      call.answer(localStream); 

                        call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {


                         $('#caller').attr('src',remoteStream);
                        });

                    }, function(err) {

                     //err
                        }


                    }
                );
        });
```

I get this error when I call the bell(numero)  function

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'call'

The problem is this line in my code
var call = peer.call(numero,stream);

what is wrong?

I'm not connected to internet and I use peerjs for signaling,and in my node server,I write this

```
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;
var server = new PeerServer({ port: 9000 });
```

I asked the problem in their Google group but not response yet.

PLease help

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue myself, are you using the 'peer.min.js' file? From looking at the source of it, it's version 0.2.8 whereas the 'peer.js' file hosted on their CDN is version 0.3.6.

When I switched to the version hosted at http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.js, this problem went away.

Comment: Yes It was the problem.I saw this solution the same of my post.

Comment: Yes it was the problem.I find this solution the same day of my question.